# How hero.service.ts create() adds the id number to the array (Tour of Heroes)

Tags: javascript, json, angular, rxjs

I'm doing the Tour of Heroes tutorial on angular but I'm not stuck I just have a question.

how does the create() function in hero.service.ts add the id number to the JSON array I can't seem to find where this is set and the thing seems to know how to number the list id number even after a delete and add!?!

```
    create(name: string): Promise<Hero> {
     return this.http
       .post(this.heroesUrl, JSON.stringify({name: name}), {headers:   this.headers})
       .toPromise()
       .then(res => res.json().data)
       .catch(this.handleError)
    }
```

Just a little confused and this would help out my understanding of this function a little better.

Thank you,
Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the courtesy of the `InMemoryDataService` class that the Tour of Heroes application uses for storing Hero entities. The source for the whole service is available here:

https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api

If you check the `post` method [here](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/src/in-memory-backend.service.ts#L547), you'll see the following code block:

```
if (!item.id) {
      item.id = id || this.genId(collection);
}
```

Where `genId(...)` is:

```
  protected genId(collection: any): any {
    // assumes numeric ids
    let maxId = 0;
    collection.reduce((prev: any, item: any) => {
      maxId = Math.max(maxId, typeof item.id === 'number' ? item.id : maxId);
    }, null);
    return maxId + 1;
  }
```

Essentially it creates a new numeric value that is an increment of the previously known largest id value.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot man I was spending way to much time trying to figure it out then i should have.  I knew it wasn't in the code I wrote.  This is a good little piece of code for future use though.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget: you can accept this answer if it was the correct solution. Read more about upvoting/accepting answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Thanks again @Andras